# How to save settings from an windows form app using a savedialog

Tags: c#, visual-studio, windows-forms-designer, savefiledialog

I have a word search creator app. The user inputs a list of words, width and height settings, word placement settings etc. When the user clicks the save button, I would like for these settings to be saved to a file, so that later the user can open the app with the saved settings. I have no idea how to do this though. (except for opening the savefiledialog)

Comment: You might be interested in reading about serialization: http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms233843.aspx

Comment: To follow up on @ChrisLaplante, I would suggest you use XML serialization. It's incredibly easy once you get how it works. Just a few attributes on the classes to serialize and VOILÀ! http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.xml.serialization.xmlserializer%28v=vs.110%29.aspx

Answer (score 1):

Open project properties, and select "settings" on left tab.  You can add any settings you want to persist there.

[image]

Capture whatever setting you want from the user and then do something like:

```
        var setting = new Settings();
        setting.MyCustomSetting = "UserSeting here";
        setting.Save();
```

These settings are saved in the app.config.

Answer (score 0):

The SaveFileDialog only provides your application with a GUI Save As window that allows the user to choose a save location and filename. The Dialog comes with an event handler (which I believe is called FileOK) where you can access mySaveFileDialog.Filename .

No data or file has actually been saved yet. To do that, you could take a variety of routes, but the simplest is using System.IO.StreamWriter:

```
using System.IO;
...
StreamWriter sw = new StreamWriter(mySaveFileDialog.Filename); //Pass the chosen filename
sw.WriteLine( string goes here );
sw.Close();
```

You'll have to come up with a string representation of your data, though.

For more complex types, use XML serialization. You can define a data structure as a class and then use .NET's built in System.Xml.Serialization namespace to automatically output a representation of the class to an easy to read XML file:

```
public class MyWordGame {
   public string[] myWords;
   public int height;
   ...
}

...
XmlSerializer xmlOut = new XmlSerializer(MyWordGame.GetType());
xmlOut.Serialize(new FileStream(mySaveFileDialog.Filename), new MyWordGame());
```

You can then do the reverse (Deserializing) to recover the original class from an XML file

There are plenty of tutorials about XML serialization out there that you should look at.